# Getting specific entries of a log file using awk

Tags: awk, logs, xml

I'm currently trying to use awk to grab items from massive log files matching specific criteria. Essentially, I need to be able to pull the entire command, marked by a transaction ID, based on information contained within the command (which can be and regularly is in a different place on the command). Example log below (highly condensed). Note that the sent command can either be a one liner, or spread across many lines (as in 00001 and 00002), and the commands aren't necessarily grouped together, there can be other IDs interspersed between:

```
(NAME, 486, 00001) <xml><command:name>target</command:name></xml>
(NAME, 486, 00001)   <response>
(NAME, 486, 00001)     <result code="200">
(NAME, 486, 00001)       <msg>Command failed</msg>
(NAME, 486, 00001)     </result>
(NAME, 486, 00001)  </response>
(FOO, 486, 00002) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) <differentCommand:name>This is another sent command</differentCommand:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00002)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00002)  </response>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003) <xml><command:name>target</command:name></xml>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   <response>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     <result code="400">
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     </result>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   </response>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <command:name>This is another sent command</command:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00004)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00004)  </response>
```

Essentially, I'd want to return the entirety of command:name inclusive of the response (the 5 digit number in parens is the transaction ID), but only where it was successful (result code="400").

This is what I have so far:

```bash
BEGIN { FS="[(,)]"; }
$4 ~ "<command:name" { id[$3] = $3 }

{ for (i in id) {
        if ($3 == i) {
                if ($5 ~ "Command completed success")
                        success[i] = i;
                }
        }
}

$4 in success { print $0 }
```

But obviously this won't go back *up* to grab the rest of the entry once it finds a success. It only returns:

```
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     </result>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   </response>
(FOO, 486, 00004)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00004)  </response>
```

I tried putting a loop in the BEGIN statement, but it takes a very long time, and I run into memory issues trying to use an array of the size it becomes (these files are over 1 GB).

What I'm hoping to return would be:

```
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003) <xml><command:name>target</command:name></xml>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   <response>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     <result code="400">
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     </result>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   </response>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <command:name>This is another sent command</command:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00004)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00004)  </response>
```

I wonder if what I'm trying is even possible in awk? I've been trying to figure out which tool to use for this task for some time now, and awk certainly seems the best as far as I can tell (short of having to use Python). Speed is my main concern, only today's files are available in plain text format (so those are fast enough), but the rest are gzipped (so I'm doing `zcat filename | awk -f test.awk`) - I'm trying to avoid having to read the file multiple times, and they're too big to be stored in memory.

Comment: FYI: python is a much better and faster language than shell for processing text (shell shouldn't be used at all for that job), but both awk and perl are far better choices than python - both will be many times faster than python (typically at least 10 or 20 times faster, depending on algorithm).

Comment: How commonly is  `XML` in use as a logfile format? Do you have raw logfiles you can parse instead? (Thinking here you might be have an option of tackling a smaller file...).

Comment: @cas that's good to know, thanks - I've started learning Perl (this isn't the only parsing of these files I need to do)

Comment: @jubilatious1 these are raw log files, there aren't smaller files I can deal with unfortunately

Comment: Thanks. I know Raku has a streaming JSON parser (`JSON::Stream`), but I don't know if it has a streaming XML parser.

Comment: You may be able to improve performance even further by using `pigz -d` instead of `zcat`.  [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) is a multi-threaded implementation of gzip that can use multiple CPU cores/threads. It greatly speeds up **compression** of files on multi-core systems, and can also provide modest but noticeable performance improvements for **decompression**.  pigz should be available as a package for most, if not all, linux distros (e.g. `sudo apt-get install pigz` on debian and derivatives).  `pigz` command-line options are compatible with `gzip`, it's meant to be a drop in replacement.

Comment: also worth noting: with the [IO::Compress::Gunzip](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) module (a standard library module included with perl), perl can transparently read gzip compressed files.  It provides no performance improvement over gzip (and is probably a little slower than reading a pipe from zcat), but can make it a lot easier to write scripts that process both compressed and uncompressed files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `</response>` as the end-of-record marker.  For example:

```
$ awk -F'[ )]' '{record[$3] = record[$3] "\n" $0};

                /<\/response>/ {
                  if (record[$3] ~ /completed successfully/) {
                    # optional: remove leading newline if you don't want
                    # a blank line before each output record:
                    # sub(/\n/,"",record[$3])

                    print record[$3]
                  };
                  delete record[$3]
                }' input.log 

(FOO, 486, 00002) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) <differentCommand:name>This is another sent command</differentCommand:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00002)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00002)  </response>

(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003) <xml><command:name>target</command:name></xml>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   <response>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     <result code="400">
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     </result>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   </response>

(FOO, 486, 00004) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <command:name>This is another sent command</command:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00004)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00004)  </response>
```

This works similarly to the sed+perl & sed+awk versions below, but it constructs each record itself by appending each line (preceded by a newline) to the appropriate element (i.e. the id number) of an array called `record`.  When it sees a `</response>` line, it prints the element if it matches "completed successfully" and then deletes that element.

This will be a fair bit slower than the sed + awk or sed + perl versions (because it has to *append each input line to an element of the array* - which uses significantly more CPU power than `sed` just inserting a blank line every so often), and use a little more memory (because each record stays in memory until there is a `</response>` line for it), but not excessively so....it keeps each record in memory only as long as needed and then deletes it.

This version should, however, work even if the records for any given id are interleaved with records for other ids.

Here's a perl equivalent:

```
perl -F'[\h)]' -e '
  $record{$F[2]} .= $_;

  if (/<\/response>/) {
    if ($record{$F[2]} =~ /completed successfully/) {
      # print blank line between records
      print "\n" if $not_first_record++;

      print $record{$F[2]}
    }
    delete $record{$F[2]};
  }' input.log
```

My testing (with a 120 MB input file containing 100,000 copies of your sample data) indicates that the awk version is almost twice as fast.  The awk version ran in around 4.6 seconds on my test system (an ancient AMD Phenom II 1090T), while the perl version took about 7.4 seconds.

###### Update

Here's an optimised perl version:

Instead of using a regex matching either horizontal whitespace or a close-parenthesis (`[\h)]`) as the field separator, it uses the perl default of white-space separation.
It extracts the key for each record from the third field and then chops off the last character (the `)`).

This version runs in about 3.9 seconds, almost twice as fast - showing that there's a huge performance penalty when using a regex for the `-F` auto-split pattern.

BTW, I tried using an indexed array for the record instead of an associative array (i.e. `@record` with numeric indices rather than `%record` with string keys) but it made no noticeable difference in performance.  I also tried using the `index()` function instead of a regex match (`index($record{$key},"completed successfully")` instead of `$record{$F[2]} =~ /completed successfully/`) but this made no noticeable performance difference, either.

```
perl -ane '
  chop($key = $F[2]);
  $record{$key} .= $_;

  if (/<\/response>/) {
    if ($record{$key} =~ /completed successfully/) {
      print "\n" if $not_first_record++;
      print $key, $record{$key};
    }
    delete $record{$key}
  }' input.log
```

The same optimisation improves awk's performance too, although not as dramatically.

awk doesn't have a `chop()` function but `substr()` can be used to do the same thing.

```
awk '{
       key = substr($3, 1, length($3)-1);
       record[key] = record[key] "\n" $0
     };

     /<\/response>/ {
       if (record[key] ~ /completed successfully/) {
         sub(/^\n/,"",record[key])
         print record[key]
       };
       delete record[key]
     }' input.log
```

This version runs in about 3.5 seconds (about 30% faster than the previous awk version's 4.6 seconds).

Overall, the updated awk and perl versions are much closer in performance, but awk is still around 12% faster.

Small changes to the code can make very large differences in performance.

---

Alternatively:

Are your log entries always neatly separated by id like that or are they interleaved with other ids?

If they are neatly separated, one of the easiest methods is to use `sed` to break it up into "paragraphs" (i.e. separated by one or more blank lines) by inserting a blank line **BEFORE** each `<xml>` line.

Then pipe `sed`'s output into either `awk` or `perl` to read the log in "paragraph mode". For awk, set `RS=""` in the BEGIN block (or with the `-v` option), in perl use the `-00` command-line option.   Then your awk or perl script only has to check if the record contains "completed successfully".  If it does, print the record:

This should run noticeably faster and use less memory than the awk-only version above...but only works corrrectly if the records **aren't** interleaved with other records.

```
$ sed '/) <xml>/i\\n' input.log |
    perl -00 -ne 'print if /completed successfully/m'
(FOO, 486, 00002) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) <differentCommand:name>This is another sent command</differentCommand:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00002)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00002)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00002)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00002)  </response>

(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003) <xml><command:name>target</command:name></xml>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   <response>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     <result code="400">
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)     </result>
(ANOTHERNAME, 486, 00003)   </response>

(FOO, 486, 00004) <xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) <command:name>This is another sent command</command:name></xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004) </xml>
(FOO, 486, 00004)   <response>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     <result code="400">
(FOO, 486, 00004)       <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
(FOO, 486, 00004)     </result>
(FOO, 486, 00004)  </response>
```

Or using awk:

```
sed '/) <xml>/i\\n' input.log | awk -v RS='' '/completed successfully/'
```

The output from this version is almost the same, but without a blank line between each output record.

Personally, I find the blank line between each output record to be useful, because it makes it easier to further process the output if necessary, as it's already in "paragraph mode".  Of course this is just a subjective preference.

---

Comment: So the records are _mostly_ together, but the server is load-balanced, and the log file is usually split across multiple files, and they're not necessarily in order (currently I just zcat for the filename across multiple folders).

I meant to mention the order in my original question, will update it

Comment: Using the closing response tag as the end marker is a great idea though, and likely something I can work with. Think I still run into issues where records are interspersed with each other though, or where they're spread across multiple files (though the latter here I'm not overly concerned about)

Comment: You can always give multiple filenames to awk, it will just process them one after another. or pipe from `zcat`, or `find ... -exec zcat -f {} + | awk '...'`, and awk will process one continuous stream of stdin (BTW, with `-f`, zcat acts like plain cat for any uncompressed files).  Interleaved records shouldn't be a problem even with multiple input files, each record will be held in memory (in the records array) until a `</response>` line is seen for that record id - that won't change just because a record happens to begin in one input file and end in another.

Comment: I've just tried the first suggestion here, and it works perfectly, I can filter down on the results of this further, thank you!

Comment: Is there a faster way to do the awk-only version entirely in Perl? I've used a2p and tweaked the script to function basically identically, but it actually appears to be slower than just straight awk...

Comment: `a2p` gives non-optimal results - it's useful as a tool for quickly converting an awk script to perl but, if performance or use of standard perl idioms are important, you should use its output as a guide for writing an optimised perl script.  I'll add a perl-only version...but the awk version is still likely to be about twice as fast.  For some tasks, awk can be noticeably faster than perl. perl really shines when you need complex data structures (not the case here, it's just a simple associative array) or when you need one of the approx 200,000 [perl library modules](https://www.cpan.org/)

Comment: That's great, thank you again! My problem is that the awk script seems to take in excess of 20 minutes to go through an entire day of logs (1.5GB+). I'm guessing I'll just have to accept that

Comment: Yeah, it takes time to read and process that amount of data.  BTW, I figured out an optimisation for the perl-only version that gets it to run about 20% faster than the awk version (4.0 seconds for 120MB rather than 4.8).  Instead of using a regex (`[\h)]`) for the auto-split, I just used the default of splitting on whitespace and then used the `chop()` function to remove the last character (`)`).  This gives the same value from the third field, but faster.  The same optimisation also works in awk, so the awk version now takes only 3.4 seconds.  I'll update my answer with the new versions.

Comment: Thank you again Cas, you're an absolute gem. I really hadn't considered the performance impact using regex has, but it makes sense